# Change view class on a tabbarcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I have one tabbarcontroller set as main controller and its views were configured using interface builder. Now, programmaticaly, I would like to change default class view. How can it be done? For example, one tab view is set from class1 and I would like to set it from class2. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you meant, but to assign different view controllers programmatically to a tabbarcontroller you can use this:

```
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstTab alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstTab" bundle:NSBundle.mainBundle];
    UINavigationController *firstNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondTab alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondTab" bundle:NSBundle.mainBundle];
    UINavigationController *secondNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController2];
    myTabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    myTabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstNavController, secondNavController, nil];
```

Comment: following with your example names, FirstTab and SecondTab generates an alert ("method alloc not found") and when running crashes returning Sigabrt error. FirstTab and SecondTab were defined at .h and has a IBOutlet set at xib. What am I doing wrong?? Thank you

Comment: you need of course to import FirstTab.h and SecondTab.h - they are separate classes / view controllers. BTW - you dont need to use IB here - this is a fully programmatically solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would add and remove a tab bar item rather than changing the view controller of a single item.

Probably not animated.